# FindBugs in Intellij - Possible to reuse .fbpref file?

Tags: java, plugins, findbugs

Originally Eclipse was dominating, so settings made in the Eclipse IDE are now being transferred to IntelliJ.

I am in the process of installing a Findbugs plugin for IntelliJ. I came across FindBugs-IDEA and QAPlug-Findbugs.

I checked both and they require a .xml file as possible "ruleset". I only have the .fbpref file from eclipse though, which looks like that:

```
...
detectorAppendingToAnObjectOutputStream=AppendingToAnObjectOutputStream|true
detectorAtomicityProblem=AtomicityProblem|true
detectorBadAppletConstructor=BadAppletConstructor|false
detectorBadResultSetAccess=BadResultSetAccess|true
detectorBadSyntaxForRegularExpression=BadSyntaxForRegularExpression|true
...
```

Is it possible to convert this to a .xml-file that is accepted by one of the plugins i mentioned?
Is there any documentation on how a .xml file for these plugins should look like? I have tried googling it but I had no luck.

It seems that using a configuration file to configure the behavior of the FindBugs-plugin is somewhat unusual practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have installed the FindBugs plugin, an XML file already exists:

```
project/.idea/findbugs-idea.xml
```

There is however no converter for `.fbprefs`. You can open both settings windows:

- Eclipse: `Project > Properties > FindBugs`
- IntelliJ: `File > Settings > Other Settings > FindBugs-IDEA`

and copy those settings manually. You can also open both files (`xml` and `.fbprefs`) and move some settings a little faster by copy&paste (especially the detectors).

There is a great service called [Transformy](http://www.transformy.io), which can transform those detectors easily. Insert your detector lines in the left panel:

```
detectorAppendingToAnObjectOutputStream=AppendingToAnObjectOutputStream|false
detectorAtomicityProblem=AtomicityProblem|true
detectorBCPMethodReturnCheck=BCPMethodReturnCheck|false
....
```

and use this as a format to transform:

```
<entry key="AppendingToAnObjectOutputStream" value="false" />
```

Unfortunately, it messes up rules which contain numbers, like `FindSelfComparison2`, so copy those manually.